# Enable dBASE III program to print on USB printer

Tags: usb, dbase, parallel-port

I have a friend with an ancient dBase III program. He says it does not print when connected to a USB parallel port printer and is considering converting the program to MS-Access. There are some 400 forms and reports, however, so I am wondering if there are other more cost-effective ways to solve this problem.

Comment: This question is really off-topic for StackOverflow. However, you might tell your friend to make sure that the USB port is set to be 'LPT1' or 'LPT2', as those were the only parallel ports supported in dBASE III's era. This can usually be set in the USB port's driver software configuration utility. Also, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587793/dos-legacy-application-with-usb-printer).

Comment: Thanks Ken. Is there a simple way in Windows to set (view) the USB port to LPT1/2? Can you suggest a more appropriate place to post this question?

Comment: As I said before, the port can usually be configured in the USB device's configuration utility. If you can't do it there, with the device connected go into the Device Manager (available in Control Panel) and see if you can configure it there. Without the specific device, I really can't offer much more. Also, did you look at the question I linked to in my first comment? AFA a more appropriate place, since it's about configuring your computer and devices I'd suggest starting at [superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Wouldn't you need a parallel cable as well?  That's the only way I have been able to get it to work in the past.  LPT1 to USB fails for me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install your usb printer and make sure it print in windows
share your printer and give it a share name...eg.."test"
get the ipadress of the pc you installed the usb printer to
open command prompt...as administrator
type..net use lpt1: \\ipadress\share name
ipadress= ipadress of the pc with usb printer
share name= test..as in the example
it will say...command completed successfully...voila you can now print